Cuda 121 - ERROR : Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch (from versions: none)
Trying to implement cuda 12.1 for some project, impossible to download torch, torchvision and torchaudio. Went to PyTorch.org but the command line (both from stable version and nightly version) e.g. pip3 install --pre torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cu121 never worked.
even if I tried some solutions posted on this page (all didnt work when it comes to options in the command line) :
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch
My error is precisely :
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch

Anybody knows what to do?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

what is your OS and python version? Is the error message you posted the complete terminal output that you get? Can you post the output when you add -v to your pip install line?

Sorry I'm on Windows and use python 3.12, but I solved it just switching to conda! Thanks for the help still.
